# How do I make it so that i can compile with g++ through the terminal?

Tags: c++, c++11, terminal, g++

Noob here. Moving on from Python to C++ (as per our university's curriculum). I'd like to know how I integrate the G++ compiler into the terminal so i could compile from there, like "g++  -o ". Also, how do I know if I do have, indeed, G++? I installed Code::Blocks and it seems to have included the compiler in the installation, but I don't know where to find it.

EDIT: I'm on MS Windows.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Look into writing a basic makefile. You should also investigate mingw.

Comment: This tut might be useful http://www.cprogramming.com/code_blocks/.  Although I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Most likely you have to add the folder with g++.exe, etc. to the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows you may need something like Cygwin to compile g++. You can find steps to install here http://www.horstmann.com/ccc/help/cygwin/install.html

Also you are very close on the right syntax that you are perhaps thinking of. It goes like *g++ -o executable_name source_file* 
hope that helps.